# Create NamedCredentials for AWS Signature via Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, soap, namedcredentials, aws

I am trying to create the named credentials for AWS using Metadata API. I am getting the following error:

```
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: 'AwsSig4' is not a valid value for the enum 'AuthenticationProtocol'.
```

As per the document, we need to use the `AwsSig4` for the AWS Signature V4:

[image]

Code:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    MetadataService.NamedCredential credential = new MetadataService.NamedCredential();
    credential.fullName = '********';
    credential.label = '**********';
    credential.endpoint = 'https://amazonaws.com';
    credential.principalType = 'NamedUser';
    credential.generateAuthorizationHeader = true;
    credential.awsRegion = '********';
    credential.awsService = '**';
    credential.awsAccessKey = '********************************';
    credential.awsAccessSecret = '*************************************';
    credential.protocol = 'AwsSig4';
            
     List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata(
            new MetadataService.Metadata[] { credential });
    
    try{
    handleSaveResults(results[0]);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('---Exception if any --- ' +e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce doc is incorrect, at least in version 48. In v48, the value of `protocol` for AWS signature is `AwsSv4`

Answer (score 1):

This is a typo in our documentation. Please use "AwsSv4" instead of "AwsSig4". This has been reported to our Platform Integration Engineering team and our document will be updated to reflect the same. Thank you